# How to send money to the particular stripe account?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, stripe-payments

I have a requirement where i have list of products and each product belongs to various seller and now the user can sign in to the application and buy the product and amount will be transferred to the corresponding seller stripe account. I am struggling with how to proceed with this.

I so far have allowed the seller to signup and connect his `stripe` account if he has already one or signup and get the code back to the app but i also wanted to know how to get the `access token` by posting the code that is received in rails and i wanted to know how the user can send the money through card to the corresponding seller.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

This is **speculative** (I don't know if you can do this with the current Stripe API):

Can't you assign the seller's stripe access tokens to the Stripe instance?

It seems the Stripe credentials are [set in an initializer](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/rails), which generally means they can't be changed; although I'd hazard a guess you can do by either calling a new instance of the `Stripe` object, or [dynamically setting the `seller` details](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/rails#configuration):

```
def create
  # Amount in cents
  @amount = 500

  seller = User.find_by id: params[:product_id]
  Stripe.api_key =  seller.stripe_api

  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => 'example@stripe.com',
    :card  => params[:stripeToken]
  )

  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :customer    => customer.id,
    :amount      => @amount,
    :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
    :currency    => 'usd'
  )

rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  redirect_to charges_path
end
```